# Format MySQL Output to Array in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have this query:

```
$query = 'SELECT `trades`.`id` AS `trade.id` FROM `trades` WHERE `id` = '. $this->trade->id . ' ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 1';
```

Which (of course) outputs

```
array(1) {
  ["trade.id"]=>
  string(2) "44"
}
```

How do I get it to output this instead?

```
array(1) {
  ["trade"]=> array(1) {
    ["id"]=> string(2) "44"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT `trades`.`id` AS `id` FROM `trades` WHERE `id` = '. $this->trade->id . ' ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 1';
$arr['trade']=$query;
print_r($arr);
```

Check It. i hope Work.....